# Help with Arizona cacti

Tags: cactus

[image] 
Hey everyone! I’ve recently been placed in charge of caring for this Arizona native cacti.  A friend of mine is travelling abroad for 8 months and I want to take good care of this little guy while she’s away. we recently had to propagate these 4 cacti pups but the “mom” is looking a little blah afterwards. Can anyone provide some tips and tricks to help me get everyone happy and healthy?

Comment: It looks like a Stenocereus thurberii (organ pipe) which is native to southern Arizona and Northern Sonora, MX. It can take lots of heat and sun once acclimatized. These normally grow over 2 meters tall and as a candelabra with many stems. As long as you let the mother plant heal before potting, it should be fine after you follow Jurp's suggestions below. Expecially the part about getting the soil a little lower on the stem. The brown on the bottom is corking which is fairly normal on large plants.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following (and I'm sure there are other posters with other ideas, too):

1. Lower the soil level right up against the cactus and cover the top of entire pot with a shallow layer of pea gravel. This is supposed to lower the chance of rot, but may also be a myth. It's what I do, however, and at least does no harm.
2. Keep the plant in full sun, if possible.
3. Before watering, check the soil at least 1" deep for moisture. It it's not completely dry, then don't water.
4. In general, water only once a month/every three weeks or so throughout the winter. Cacti houseplants are usually killed by over-watering.
   Always drain the saucer of any water remaining thirty minutes or so after you water the plant.
5. In the spring and summer, you can water more often (every one or two weeks, depending on soil dryness)

It's probably a good idea to keep the cactus on the cool side if you can - 60 degrees F or so would be fine. I would not let it get below 50 degrees F unless you know that it's from northern/colder Arizona as opposed to the southern/warmer part of the state.